# asp.net dropdownlist convert to MVC3 dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I have an static dropdown list in asp.net like below:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSource" Width="278px">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="NONE" Text="- Selct-" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="" disabled="disabled">Old customer</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="got sms" Value="OLD_SMS" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="got email" Value="OLD_EMAIL" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="othe" Value="OLD_OTHER" />

                    <asp:ListItem Value="" disabled="disabled">Heard in radio</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="radio ad" Value="RADIO_AD" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="radio programme" Value="RADIO_SHOW" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="other" Value="RADIO_OTHER" />
          </asp:DropDownList>
```

How can I implement the same thing in MVC3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it's a static list then all you need to do is:

```
<select id="ddlSource" style="width:278px;">
    <option value="NONE">- Selct-</option>
    <option disabled="disabled">Old customer</option>
    <option value="OLD_SMS">got sms</option>
  ....
</select>
```

it's just simple html.

Comment: ahhhhhh just how silly i am. My head stopped working long ago. dont know why still i am staring at my monitor...!!!!

Comment: hey no worries. Happens to us all. If you really want a dropdownlist you can always do `@Html.DropDownList("VIEWBAG/VIEWDATA", "")` and use `var foo = new SelectList(...` in your controller

Comment: yeah i know. thanks a lot. As i said, my head wasnt just working. -_- Thnks though. Again

Answer (score 2):

You can use either `Html.DropDownList()` or `Html.DropDownListFor()`. Both methods take a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` as a parameter. The "for" option takes a `Func` that points to a collection in the model, whereas the non-for option takes a collection directly. A collection can be created like this:

```
var selectList = new SelectListItem[]
{
    new SelectListItem()
    {
        Selected = true,
        Text = "Text",
        Value = "Value"
    },

    new SelectListItem()
    {
        Selected = true,
        Text = "Text1",
        Value = "Value1"
    },
};
```

Needless to say you can also do a basic `<select><option>...` with plain old HTML, but by putting the collection of `SelectListItem` into your model and using `@Html.DropDownListFor()`, you take advantage of the strongly-typed model binding that makes MVC so great.

Comment: +1 I had just commented on my own answer about using `@Html.DropDownList` before I saw your post, but the OP didn't suggest they where using a model so that's why I didn't suggest it originally.